# C# Access file in shared location with

Tags: c#, remote-access

Is it possible to read files from a shared remote network path which is not in a domain if we have the local user name and password?
We were using  **SimpleImpersonation** but it is not working when we don't have a domain for the path.

Comment: Can you give an example of such path?

Comment: it is a machine local storage @orhtej2